# Simple app for taking/storing photos on a server

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, photos, unix

I am looking for a dead-simple app to take photos (either with the camera, or from the library) and store them onto a server via WiFi.  This is for taking photos of whiteboards at work.  I really want the app to be dead-simple, automatically storing a photo to the server would be great.

I don't really care what protocol it uses to communicate with the server, but it would be great if it were not a proprietary Apple protocol, so that I could use an existing Linux file server.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: How automatic are you looking for? Like any photo you take with your iPhone, or only photos you select? I know the former is at least possible because my flickr app uploads every picture automatically. The latter is certainly doable, though no apps come to mind at the moment. There might be a Dropbox + IFTTT action that will FTP any pictures from a Dropbox folder to a server.

Answer (score 1):

[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) is likely the best for storing photos in the cloud. It allows you to easily, and simply select photos from your library and then upload them to the Dropbox cloud.

The one caveat is that it is annoying to restore images because you have to go to each picture and restore it individually. Who knows, perhaps they will come out with an update that will fix that.

Comment: It seems like the question is asking about uploading photos to an "existing Linux file server", not to the cloud.

Comment: @dwightk is correct.  I appreciate the color, tho.

Answer (score 0):

No apps come directly to mind that are that generic. Though I use PogoPlug for the very thing you describe. It is basically a private cloud. The device itself is very inexpensive, less than $50, and there are applications for all of the mobile platforms that will upload your pictures automatically. You just need to plug the PogoPlug into your network and attach an external hard drive (you can actually chain many drives to it) and let the PogoPlug device do the rest. It also provides a web interface so you can get to your data from anywhere. If you have more than one drive plugged in you can also set up a mirroring or backup task that will help in the event of a drive failure.